# Why hot observable resubscribe

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an observable that listen on table select event, it is also hot.

The code snippet:

```
  const oTableRowSelect$ = TableOb.rowSelectionChangeEvent$(this.getById("ins-table"));
  const test = oTableRowSelect$
    .do(function () {
      console.log("resubscribe");
    })
    .map(function () {
      return 4;
    });

  test.subscribe(function (o) {
    console.log("Select1" + o);
  });

  test.subscribe(function (o) {
    console.log("Select2" + o)
  });
```

As you can see, there are two subscribers, that listen on the event. So the result should share to all subscribers, that what is called a replay effect.

The output, that I've got is:
[image]

But I am expecting `resubscribe` output only once. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your `oTableRowSelect$` might be *hot* and shared, it is only shared up the the part where you extend it somehow with additional operator(s) (in your case `do` and `map`).

In RxJS any extension through an operator will basically return a *"new"* stream.
In order to make this *"new"* stream hot/shared you'd have to apply an operator that makes it hot (`share`, `publish`, `publishReplay`, ect...)

```js
const hotBaseStream$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject("Hi!");

const test = hotBaseStream$
    // -------- below this line you get a "new" stream, that is not hot any more
    .do(() => console.log("resubscribe"))
    .map(() => 4)
    .publishReplay().refCount();  // remove this part and you will have back your original behavior

  test.subscribe(function (o) {
    console.log("Select1 ", o);
  });

  test.subscribe(function (o) {
    console.log("Select2 ", o)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: In term of hot observable I understand, for example a button click event is a hot observable. When I have multiple subscriber, I expect that they receive the message at the same time.

Comment: Correct, they do receive the message at the _"same time"_ (a few nano-seconds apart probably ;-) )